# Android Q 10 Connect to network WifiNetworkSpecifier

Tags: android, connection, wifi, android-10.0

Since Android Q doesn't allow the WifiManager to add Networks, they gave the advise to use WifiNetworkSpecifier instead. 
With the WifiNetworkSuggestionBuilder I was already able to display the notification on the statusbar, that user can join the network. But this API doesn't fulfill my requirements since that I don't the user to have to use the suggestion from the statusbar.

With WifiNetworkSpecifier I was also already able to display a popup about joining the network and the app also established a connection to the app. But that wifi connection seems only be available in the scope of the app. How is it possible to overcome this scope of the app, so other apps and for example also the browser is able to use this new established connection?
Below is my code

```java
    WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder builder = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder();
    builder.setSsid("abcdefgh");
    builder.setWpa2Passphrase("1234567890");

    WifiNetworkSpecifier wifiNetworkSpecifier = builder.build();
    NetworkRequest.Builder networkRequestBuilder = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
networkRequestBuilder.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI);     
networkRequestBuilder.addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_RESTRICTED);            
networkRequestBuilder.addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_TRUSTED);            
networkRequestBuilder.setNetworkSpecifier(wifiNetworkSpecifier);
NetworkRequest networkRequest = networkRequestBuilder.build();
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) App.getInstance().getBaseContext().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (cm != null) {
        cm.requestNetwork(networkRequest, new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAvailable(@NonNull Network network) {
                //Use this network object to Send request.
                //eg - Using OkHttp library to create a service request

                super.onAvailable(network);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hey, have you managed to come across to a solution to this? Whenever I use the NetworkSpecifier, it says im "connected" to the network but I have no actual internet connectivity.

Comment: Hey, for my use case I jumped to the WifiNetworkSuggestionBuilder as @AmirZ posted. It seems like if you want to connect to a normal WifiNetwork with the WifiNetworkSpecifier, you can only access the internet capability for this app. So you won't have internet for other apps as for example Chrome

Comment: Ah that's dissapointing to hear. Thanks tho!

Comment: I tried everything to get internet with my app only, but can’t get internet connectivity no matter what I try. I can connect to the wifi after seeing the popup, but no internet even within my app.

Answer (score 5):

A bit late to the party, but maybe it will help someone else that encounters this problem.

It seems like you are right.
In android Q once the app is killed, the system automatically disconnects the WiFi network we've connected to through WifiNetworkSpecifier and there is no way to prevent the system from doing so.

The best solution I've come up with, is using WifiNetworkSpecifier with WifiNetworkSuggestion. This allows us to use WifiNetworkSpecifier while we are using our app, and suggest wifi networks for the system to auto connect to once the system disconnects from our WiFi due to the app being terminated.

Here is some sample code:

```
    WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder builder = new WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder()
        .setSsid("YOUR_SSID")
        .setWpa2Passphrase("YOUR_PASSWORD")
    WifiNetworkSuggestion suggestion = builder.build();

    ArrayList<WifiNetworkSuggestion> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(suggestion);

    WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    int status = manager.addNetworkSuggestions(list);

    if (status == STATUS_NETWORK_SUGGESTIONS_SUCCESS) {
        //We have successfully added our wifi for the system to consider
    }
```

Cheers,

Comment: This solution works when the phone does not connected to other network.

Comment: @AmirZ But does the user have to confirm the suggestion or does the system automatically connect to the suggested network once the app was killed?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there is no way to connect the user to a wifi network on android Q without any user interaction. Further more, if the user disconnected from your network manually, your network will be blacklisted for the next 24 hours, meaning you won't be able to suggest that network again during that period (The user of course can manually connect to your network if he chooses to).

Answer (score 4):

I tried this code its working fine

```
WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder builder = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder();
builder.setSsid("abcdefgh");
builder.setWpa2Passphrase("1234567890");

WifiNetworkSpecifier wifiNetworkSpecifier = builder.build();
NetworkRequest.Builder networkRequestBuilder = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
networkRequestBuilder.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI);     
networkRequestBuilder.setNetworkSpecifier(wifiNetworkSpecifier);
NetworkRequest networkRequest = networkRequestBuilder.build();
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) 
           App.getInstance().getBaseContext().getApplicationContext()
          .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
if (cm != null) {
    cm.requestNetwork(networkRequest, new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAvailable(@NonNull Network network) {
           super.onAvailable(network);
    cm.bindProcessToNetwork(network)
        }});
```

Comment: But you can't use this internet connection outside your app, right? For example for normak browsing in Chrome

Comment: @JulianSchweppe yes we can't use internet outside the app even we are not able to connect to the internet if our WiFi is off we can't turn WiFi on programmatically

Comment: I can’t even use internet within my app. Shows the wifi icon with “x” in the corner.

Comment: @KBog did u find any solution?

Comment: @R.singh I ended up sticking for API 28 which gives the app more control over wifi. Was hoping to buy some time until things get better with newer updates. It’s a matter of time for me…

Comment: @Waleed can you please help me how to add network in ok OkHttpClient for network request ?

Answer (score 0):

You must add this line for use internet.

```
networkRequestBuilder.addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET);
```