# NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces() returns null (android 29)

Tags: android, android-wifi

I run the following connectAndroidQ code to connect to open ap, and disconnectAndroidQ code to disconnect, but after connecting and disconnecting, the return value of NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces() is null.

Before executing the code below, the return value of NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces() is normal, but just running the code returns a null value.

test phone : pixel2
android version : 10

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
private boolean connectAndroidQ(@Nullable ConnectivityManager connectivityManager, ScanResult scanResult) {
    if (connectivityManager == null) {
        return false;
    }

    WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder wifiNetworkSpecifierBuilder = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
            .setSsid(scanResult.SSID);

    NetworkRequest networkRequest = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
            .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
            .setNetworkSpecifier(wifiNetworkSpecifierBuilder.build())
            .build();

    if (networkCallback != null) {
        connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(networkCallback);
    }

    networkCallback = new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAvailable(@NonNull Network network) {
            super.onAvailable(network);
            connectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork(network);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUnavailable() {
            super.onUnavailable();
        }
    };
    connectivityManager.requestNetwork(networkRequest, networkCallback);
    return true;
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
private boolean disconnectAndroidQ(@NonNull final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager) {
    if (networkCallback != null) {
        connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(networkCallback);
        networkCallback = null;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried these:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57929863/android-q-10-connect-to-network-wifinetworkspecifier
https://blog.ostebaronen.dk/2019/11/android-10-wifi.html

Comment: As I know, WifiNetworkSuggestion is for the access to the internet and WifiNetworkSpecifier is for the peer to peer. I don't understand why NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces() returns null even though I reconnected to home AP after disconnecting.

Comment: I solved that problem by calling bindProcessToNetwork(null).  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#bindProcessToNetwork(android.net.Network)

Comment: great find. you might want to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved that problem by calling bindProcessToNetwork(null).

See the link below, Note that if network ever disconnects, all Sockets created in this way will cease to work and all host name resolutions will fail. This is by design so an application doesn't accidentally use Sockets it thinks are still bound to a particular Network. To clear binding pass null for network.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#bindProcessToNetwork(android.net.Network)

Comment: Any sample code @yong?